# History of the Lewis-Stegall theorem on factorization of representable operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, ho.history-overview

The following questions are about the history of a particular result in functional analysis, hence not "mathematical questions" *per se*; but I think they are relevant to the business of writing research papers in mathematics and to curating the research literature, and I think that they concern something sufficiently specialized and "recent" that MO is a more suitable place for the question than HSM.SE.

---

A bounded operator $T$ from $L_1[0,1]$ to a Banach space $X$ is said to be representable if it can be written as
$$
T(f) = \int_0^1 f(t) {\bf h}(t)\,dt
\quad\quad\hbox(f\in L_1)
$$
for some bounded and strongly measurable function ${\bf h}: [0,1]\to X$. The following result is known as the *Lewis—Stegall theorem:*

**Theorem A.** $T:L_1[0,1]\to X$ is representable if and only if there exist bounded operators $S:L_1[0,1]\to\ell_1$ and $R:\ell_1\to X$ such that $T=RS$.

The proof can be found in various books, with varying degrees of self-contained-ness. (Three such sources known to me are the Diestel–Uhl book on *Vector Measures*, the appendices of the Defant–Floret book on *Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals*, and Ryan's *Introduction to Tensor Products of Operator Spaces*) However, I am having difficulty tracking down the first place in the literature where this result was explicitly stated and attributed to Lewis and Stegall.

Diestel and Uhl give as a reference the 1973 paper of Lewis and Stegall (J. Functional Analysis) on *Banach spaces whose duals are isomorphic to $l_1(\Gamma)$* but the paper itself never actually mentions representable operators. It does seem that one can extract a proof of Theorem A from results in their paper, provided one knows an alternative characterization of representable operators as those whose composition with the canonical map $L_\infty[0,1]\to L_1[0,1]$ is nuclear, but the earliest explicit reference I have found for that characterization is in a 1976 paper of Linde (Math. Nachricten) although it seems to have been known to various authors at the time.

The best I have managed so far is the appendix of Rosenthal's 1975 Bull. AMS article on *The Banach spaces $C(K)$ and $L^p(\mu)$* where "Theorem A" occurs, albeit with slightly different terminology, as Theorem A3. In the proof Rosenthal does not explicitly credit the result to Lewis and Stegall, but he mentions that for a representable $T$

> We are indebted to D. Lewis for the observation that $T$ may be realized as an "$l^1$-sum" of compact operators, each of which may be factored through $l^1$ by the "lifting property"
> of $L^1(\lambda)$-spaces.

Indeed this decomposition as a block-diagonal "sum" of compact operators does occur in the original paper of Lewis and Stegall, but as mentioned above they were working with the "$L_\infty[0,1]\to L_1[0,1]\to X$ is nuclear" formulation rather than representability by an element of $L_\infty([0,1];X)$.

**Question 1.** What is the earliest record in the literature where Theorem A is stated as above and attributed to Lewis and Stegall?

(I am not trying to deny them credit since there seems to be consensus that they were fully aware that methods from their paper yielded this result, but I am a little frustrated when I have to hunt down papers in the literature only to find that they do not say what the secondary literature claims they say.)

**Question 2.** Given that the MO readership includes some long-standing members of the community of Banach space theory, does anyone have anecdotal/verbal information of how Theorem A — rather than the headline result of the JFA 1973 paper — came to be known as the Lewis–Stegall theorem?

Comment: Well, Lewis, Stegall, and Rosenthal are still around, so maybe one of them will clarify. I was at the conference in Baton Rouge organized by Ron Retherford at which Stegall spoke on the Lewis-Stegall result. IIRC, Rosenthal was finding Stegall's somewhat  abstract presentation hard to follow. He was sitting by Lewis and started questioning him, and Lewis showed him the observation he mentioned in your quote from his 1975 Bulletin article. $$$$ I have no doubt that Lewis and Stegall knew everything attributed to them.

Comment: Thanks @BillJohnson - I was tempted to try and resurrect the ask-johnson tag just for this question :)

Comment: This appears to be one instance of what Pietsch refers to by saying ``Mathematicians invent their own history.''

Comment: Another book containing the proof of the Lewis-Stegall theorem is Pisier's Martingales in Banach spaces. I am afraid that, on that specific result, the Notes do not contain more information on the history than other sources. Page 73, Pisier writes "The Lewis-Stegall theorem comes from [the 1973 paper by Lewis-Stegall]", and refers to Diestel and Uhl "for a more detailed history of the RNP and more precise references".